# How to scale web application in kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Let's consider a python web application deployed under uWSGI via Nginx.

> HTTP client ↔ Nginx ↔ Socket/HTTP ↔ uWSGI (web server) ↔ webapp

Where nginx is used as reverse proxy / load balancer.

**How to scale this kind of applications in kubernetes?**
Several options come to my mind:

1. Deploy nginx and uWSGI in a single pod. Simple approach.
2. Deploy nginx + uWSGI in single container? Violate the “one process per container” principle.
3. Deploy only a uWSGI (via HTTP). Omit the usage of nginx.

or there is another solution, involving nginx ingress/load balancer services?

Comment: How are using any kind of ingress controller or just the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

I see two scenarios:

1. **Ingress is used**

   In this case there's no need to have nginx server within the pod, but it can be `ingress-nginx` which will be balancing traffic across a kubernetes cluster. You can find a good example in [this comment on GitHub issue](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/143#issuecomment-347814243).
2. **No ingress is used.**

   In this case I'd go with `option 1` - `Deploy nginx and uWSGI in a single pod. Simple approach.`. This way you can easily scale in/out your application and don't have any complicated/unnecessary dependencies.

In case you're not familiar with `what ingress is`, please find [kubernetes documentation - ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).